# A fellow agent requires your help

Tags: cipher, steganography

Agent,
One of your fellow field agents has dropped off documents at a specified location, however as a tech-incompetent FBI boss I have no clue what's wrong with the message they sent me.
Could you get me the Agent's name and the co-ordinates of the document drop-off? It'll be a bonus if you can tell me the name of the building.
Of course, it's totally top secret, so please remember to hide sensitive information in spoiler tags (that way the terrorists don't see it!).

~ Your Boss

Attached Files: [TS // Document Locations.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0gfQvWCwbizZkZvM2FFLTJtaVU/view?dl=1)
(Edit: sorry, first time doing this. Link should be open to all now.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution**:

> You should go to 33°47'01.8"N 84°23'24.6"W, which looks on Google Maps like the site of [Turner Broadcasting System](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@33.783675,-84.3905781,3a,75y,96.18h,101.56t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sedPuyEfRCozkp29fqOAaYA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=en). As @LeppyR64 figured out, the agent's name is Georgia.

**Explanation**:

<sup>@kamenf solved these parts:</sup>

The text file sent to us is actually:

> A `.png` image, which can be obtained by changing the extension:
>  [image].

After decrypting from MaxiCode it reads

> `Agent: Please ask safely, take enough. Bus is near. com KJdVSUcF`.

Which, taking the first letter of each word, leads us to:

> [pastebin.com/KJdVSUcF](http://pastebin.com/KJdVSUcF)

<sup>The following was solved by @LeppyR64:</sup>

Decrypting the PGP message will result in:

> Hello, fellow agent.
>  You can find the important
>  documents inside.
>  http://bit.ly/33per783833N

Going to the address given above shows this image:

> [image: Peaches]

<sup>These are the last bits that I solved:</sup>

Running that image through steghide produces:

> The Western co-ordinates are: -84.390174

And the northern co-ordinates are:

> The latter part of the bit.ly address from earlier.

So, putting that all together, we can deduce that:

> We should go to [33°47'01.8"N, 84°23'24.6"W](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/33%C2%B047'01.8%22N+84%C2%B023'24.6%22W/@33.7838093,-84.3902699,21z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d33.783833!4d-84.390174?hl=en), which looks like the site of TBS Inc.

Comment: Good work!  What's the agent's name?

Comment: @LeppyR64 It should be obvious, but I haven't seen it yet.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Unless it's 'Agent' ;)

Comment: @LeppyR64 already found it - the name of the PGP signer. Well done! I hope you all enjoyed. Also the last name is the alternate name of the building, as the studio production company that occupys that space.

Comment: @dylmye Welcome to PSE! This was a great first puzzle, I hope you'll write some more!

Answer (score 8):

Partial:

> The text file is actually PNG image:
>  [image]
>
>  Decoded from MaxiCode it reads:
>
>   **Agent: Please ask safely, take enough. Bus is near. com KJdVSUcF**
>
>   Which (taking first letters of the words) leads to [pastebin.com/KJdVSUcF](http://pastebin.com/KJdVSUcF)

Comment: How'd you get an image from the text?

Comment: @Neon612 Simple renaming of the file to have png extension

Comment: Why didn't I think of that

Comment: what do you mean by renaming the file ?

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat changing the file extension from txt to png.

Answer (score 5):

Continuing on from Kamenf:

The Adding the PGP signature into Kleopatra shows that the agents name is:

> Georgia Williams (I live up to my name.)

Decrypting the PGP message gives:

> Hello, fellow agent.
>  You can find the important
>  documents inside.
>  http://bit.ly/33per783833N

Which is the following picture:

> [image]

Interesting:

> She's a Georgia Peach ;)

Based on the hexedit of the file:

> There is only one file, so any other data must be inscribed within the file.

Comment: Hint: If you're stuck, study the question and its tags more closely. As you know I'm incompetent and probably left something identifying there. ~ Your Boss

Comment: @dylmye I see the tag, just don't know what to do with it.

Comment: won't give too much away, but what else can you hide in a image, and what methods/software?